# Creating Dynamic Pivots with Grouping on the Fly

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, xml-parsing, pivot-table, advanceddatagrid

I would like to create a pivot as shown here: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Grid/HierarchicalAdvancedDataGridColumnGrouping.htm

How ever I want to be able to do this dynamically.

The usage in the project is to be able to represent any data from a database, with any number of possible groupings on the horizontal and vertical axis.

Could someone offer some guidance on the most efficient structure to get an XML return in order to build these kind's of pivots on the fly. All the examples I have seen are statically defined. What I would like to do is be able to have a structure for a return that could give any level of grouping and data return from a web service call.

The tool I'm building is a reporting tool, so users could drag any DB field into column or row potentially so the key thing is the ability to define and build "any structure" a user would want.

Please and thank you for your help.